# What can make you lose a Ban in the LCS?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

I'm just starting to watch the FNC vs CW game, and Fnatic only has the right to ban once (instead of 3 times). The commentators didn't seem to say why it was so, but they talked about Fnatic only having 1 ban instead of 3 even before the ban phase starts, so it was not a mistake by Fnatic to forget to ban.

So what, in the current rules of the LCS, can make you lose a ban?

Comment: http://riot-web-static.s3.amazonaws.com/lolesports/LCS%202014%20Regular%20Season%20Ruleset%201.01%20FINAL.pdf dont break those

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you break any of the rules mentioned [here](http://riot-web-static.s3.amazonaws.com/lolesports/LCS%202014%20Regular%20Season%20Ruleset%201.01%20FINAL.pdf) you will be subjected to the penalties also mentioned.  In the specific instance, Fnatic and Roccat both lost a ban for calling unauthorized pauses, and Fnatic lost a second ban for talking during a pause.

[Fnatic Tweet](https://twitter.com/RiotaBhorsen/status/429001990329204736)

[Roccat Tweet](https://twitter.com/RiotaBhorsen/status/429002576013438976)

Unauthorized Pause rule:

> If a player pauses or unpauses a game without
>   permission from an LCS official, it will be considered unfair play and
>   penalties will be applied at the discretion of LCS officials.

Talking during pause rule:

> For the fairness of all competing teams, players are not allowed to
>   speak to each other during a game pause. For the avoidance of doubt,
>   players may communicate to the referee, but only when directed in
>   order to identify and remedy the cause for the stoppage. If a pause
>   extends long enough, referees may, at their sole discretion, allow
>   teams to talk before the game is unpaused, in order to discuss the
>   game conditions.

All of the rules are too long to list here, but the possible punishments are:

1. Verbal Warning(s)
2. Loss of Side Selection for Current or Future Game(s)
3. Loss of Ban for Current or Future Game(s)
4. Fine(s) and/or Prize Forfeiture(s)
5. Game Forfeiture(s)
6. Match Forfeiture(s)
7. Suspension(s)
8. Disqualification(s)

Comment: What does 'calling unauthorized pauses' mean?

Comment: @RoneRackal editted to add the actual rules they broke but the reasons for pausing are gone into detail in the pdf of the rules

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you lose bans when you break rules. In the case you are referring too, Fnatic did talk with each other during the break of the previous game against CW, which their are not allow to do.

Comment: Thanks! Would be a perfect answer with a list of the rules that could provoke the ban loss.

Comment: @Fredy31 I'm working on it. Not sure it exists.